# "Failed to execute tools\android.bat" error when I run SDK Manager

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

I tried to run android.bat file in command prompt and I got the error in the link below. I have already installed JDK,  what's the problem?

[image]

In the background window :
"Failed to execute tools\android:bat the system cannot find the file specified."

I think the problem is in the code of Android.bat but I can't fix the problem:

```
    @echo off
rem Copyright (C) 2007 The Android Open Source Project
rem
rem Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
rem you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
rem You may obtain a copy of the License at
rem
rem      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
rem
rem Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
rem distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
rem WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
rem See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
rem limitations under the License.

rem Useful links:
rem Command-line reference:
rem   http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490890.aspx

rem don't modify the caller's environment
setlocal

rem Set up prog to be the path of this script, including following symlinks,
rem and set up progdir to be the fully-qualified pathname of its directory.
set prog=%~f0

rem Grab current directory before we change it
set work_dir=%cd%

rem Change current directory and drive to where the script is, to avoid
rem issues with directories containing whitespaces.
cd /d %~dp0


rem Check we have a valid Java.exe in the path.
set java_exe=
call lib\find_java.bat
if not defined java_exe goto :EOF

set jar_path=lib\sdkmanager.jar;lib\swtmenubar.jar

rem Set SWT.Jar path based on current architecture (x86 or x86_64)
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('"%java_exe%" -jar lib\archquery.jar') do set swt_path=lib\%%a

:MkTempCopy
    rem Copy android.bat and its required libs to a temp dir.
    rem This avoids locking the tool dir in case the user is trying to update it.

    set tmp_dir=%TEMP%\temp-android-tool
    xcopy %swt_path% %tmp_dir%\%swt_path% /I /E /C /G /R /Y /Q > nul
    copy /B /D /Y lib\common.jar         %tmp_dir%\lib\        > nul
    copy /B /D /Y lib\commons-codec*     %tmp_dir%\lib\        > nul
    copy /B /D /Y lib\commons-compress*  %tmp_dir%\lib\        > nul
    copy /B /D /Y lib\commons-logging*   %tmp_dir%\lib\        > nul
    copy /B /D /Y lib\dvlib.jar          %tmp_dir%\lib\        > nul
    copy /B /D /Y lib\guava*             %tmp_dir%\lib\        > nul
    copy /B /D /Y lib\httpclient*        %tmp_dir%\lib\        > nul
    copy /B /D /Y lib\httpcore*          %tmp_dir%\lib\        > nul
    copy /B /D /Y lib\httpmime*          %tmp_dir%\lib\        > nul
    copy /B /D /Y lib\layoutlib-api.jar  %tmp_dir%\lib\        > nul
    copy /B /D /Y lib\org-eclipse-*      %tmp_dir%\lib\        > nul
    copy /B /D /Y lib\sdk*               %tmp_dir%\lib\        > nul
    copy /B /D /Y lib\swtmenubar.jar     %tmp_dir%\lib\        > nul

    rem jar_path and swt_path are relative to PWD so we don't need to adjust them, just change dirs.
    set tools_dir=%cd%
    cd /d %tmp_dir%

:EndTempCopy

rem The global ANDROID_SWT always override the SWT.Jar path
if defined ANDROID_SWT set swt_path=%ANDROID_SWT%

if exist "%swt_path%" goto SetPath
    echo ERROR: SWT folder '%swt_path%' does not exist.
    echo Please set ANDROID_SWT to point to the folder containing swt.jar for your platform.
    goto :EOF

:SetPath
rem Finally exec the java program and end here.
REM set REMOTE_DEBUG=-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=8000
call "%java_exe% %REMOTE_DEBUG%" "-Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir=%tools_dir%" "-Dcom.android.sdkmanager.workdir=%work_dir%" -classpath "%jar_path%;%swt_path%\swt.jar" com.android.sdkmanager.Main %*

rem EOF
```

Comment: Android does not support Java 8 yet. You'll need Java 7 or 6. Also, I don't understand the foreign error message, so you will need to translate it here so we know what the error is referring to.

Comment: In the background window : "Failed to execute tools\android:bat the system cannot find the file specified."

Comment: Have you checked the ../android-sdk/tools/ directory to see if it has `android.bat` file? The error message you posted suggest that the batch file is missing. This could be an issue with the latest Android SDK v23 release.

Comment: android.bat file isn't missing, I tried also to run SDK Manager as administrator but i get the same error.

Comment: Could it be a permission problem?

Comment: Android SDK directory and sub-directories will need admin rights to run the executable or batch files. So, yes, check your directory permission.

Comment: Directory permissions are ok.

Comment: You might have to debug `android.bat` and see which command line in the batch file is failing. It's hard to say from your error where it fails.

Comment: I have updated with android.bat code